# not able to print values from sensor

Tags: python, python-2.7, raspberry-pi3

I am trying to print values from sensor but the sensor is running without showing error but it is not printing values, I am not able to understand the problem

this is the code:

```
from usbiss.spi import SPI
import numpy
import serial
import opc
import time
import csv
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Qt5Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from drawnow import *

spi = SPI("/dev/ttyACM0")
spi.mode = 1
spi.max_speed_hz = 500000
alpha = opc.OPCN2(spi)
time.sleep(2)
alpha.on()
a1 = alpha.pm()
op_sensor = serial.Serial(
    port = '/dev/ttyACM0',
    baudrate = 500000,
    parity = serial.PARITY_NONE,
    stopbits = serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
    bytesize = serial.EIGHTBITS,
    timeout=1 # add this
    ) 
count = 0
while(count<=20):
    while(op_sensor.inWaiting()==0):
        pass
    a = op_sensor.readline()
    print(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not have your sensor, but consider this for solving your problem:

- why do you use `op_sensor.inWaiting()` ? you probably need [`out_waiting` or `outWaiting()`](http://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyserial_api.html#serial.Serial.out_waiting) - you *do* want to query if the sensor has data for you

Also:

- consider incrementing `count`